# Adding slash / after any link in my site opens the page without any images

Tags: .htaccess

Any link in my site that a user or a search engine links to it and adds a slash after it shows the text only without any images, and any link in that page is not open to its path, but after the first url, so it opens that url again!

example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1.html
```

works fine.

but this doesn't:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1.html/
```

I am not using css file nor a cms, just normal html files.  The server is Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1.

this is .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.com/error404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.com\.org
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite.com/.*$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite.com.*$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://?mysite.com/.*$ [NC]  [OR]

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? And, in any case, if you don't show us your .htaccess config, we can't help you find a problem with it.

Comment: Can you show your htaccess? Are you using a CMS of any kind? Are you configuring a "base path" option or something similar anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would remove the ending `/` if your URL have one and is not an existent folder.

However like Jon Lin have mentioned on his answer if you have a multi-level file it will try to rewrite images to the closest folder, so using the absolute URL to images/css/etc is the best option.

Comment: the problem came again after adding this line to: "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf": "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .html". as I want to trat my html pages as php..  what do you suggest now?

Comment: @Mike that is a complete different issue and I doubt its even related to the above rule, you should make a new question for it.

Comment: when I remove that line your first answer works well..  so it is related to it..  I'll ask a new question, thanks.

Comment: @Mike That line ? there are 5 lines above on my answer which one are you referring to.

Comment: I meant the line I added in apache2.conf

Comment: @Mike Oh you mean the line on your first comment which is completely unrelated to the answer. Well that's not how you do it. You will need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18972017/342740 but for html which is indeed unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

In your html content, you need to either change your relative links (ones that don't start with a `/`) to absolute links (ones that start with a `/`) or create a relative URI base in the `<head>` portion of your page:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: ya it works, but I didn't want to do that, as local files on the pc won't work then