# Redirect loop with simple htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have been pulling my air out over this. It worked before the server migration!

Ok so basically it's as simple as this:

I have a .php file that I want to view the content of using a SEO friendly URL via a ReWrite rule.

Also to canonicalise and to prevent duplicate content I want to 301 the .php version to the SEO friendly version.

This is what I used and has always worked till now on the new server:

```
RewriteRule ^friendly-url/$ friendly-url.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^friendly-url.php$ /friendly-url/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However disaster has struck and now it causes a redirect loop.

Logically I can only assume that in this version of Apache it is tripping up as it's seeing that the script being run is the .php version and so it tries the redirect again.

How can I re-work this to make it work? Or is there a config I need to switch in WHM?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how your `.htaccess` should look like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /friendly-url.php to /friendly-url/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(friendly-url)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L]

## To internally redirect /anything/ to /anything.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Note how I am using `R=302`, because I don't want the rule to cache on my browser until I confirm its working as expected, then, once I can confirm its working as expected I switch from `R=302` to `R=301`.

Keep in mind you may have also been cached from previous attempts since you're using `R=301`, so you better of trying to access it from a different browser you have used just to make sure its working.

> However disaster has struck and now it causes a redirect loop.

It causes a redirect loop because your redirecting it to itself, the different on my code is that I capture the request, and redirect the php files from there to make it friendly and then use the internal redirect.

Comment: This is a **really** good answer, however I need to do it on a per file basis as my website is old and due a re-build on a good CMS that handles all this. I'll check the caching of the browser in the mean time.. Thanks!

Comment: Also what does -MultiViews do out of interest?

Comment: See update for only a single URL, you can also use `(friendly-url|anotherurl|another)` instead of copying several rules. [As for `-MultiViews`, see here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

Comment: Thanks @Prix can you break down whats going on in the internal redirect because I'm concerned about if I have a directory for example then we dont want to look for .php as an example. Just testing it out!

Comment: @Stefan `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(friendly-url)\.php [NC]` more specifically `/+(friendly-url)\.php` is looking if your URL is: `http://domain.com/friendly-url.php`, if yes then it takes only the `friendly-url` portion of it and redirect to `http://domain.com/friendly-url/` the code at the bottom is in charge of taking any URL that does not exist for example `http://domain.com/friendly-url/` but have a php file available and internally redirect to that PHP file, so in short if a folder exist under that name it will not redirect.

Comment: works beautifully, very nice and clean, great explanation and responses and I have learnt something new and I'm sure others will from this as well. Great answer, accepted thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was easy to understand because I suck at explaining `.htaccess` rules or rather REGEX in general hehe.

Answer (score 2):

The exact same .htaccess file will work differently depending on where it's placed because the [L]ast flag means something different depending on location. In ...conf, [L]ast means all finished processing so get out, but in .htaccess the exact same [L]ast flag means *start all over at the top of this file*.

To work as expected when moving a block of code from ...conf to .htaccess, most .htaccess files will need one or the other of these tweaks:

- Change the [L]ast flags to [END]. (Problem is, the [END] flag is only available in newer [version 2.3.9 and later] Apaches, and won't even "fall back" in earlier versions.)
- Add boilerplate code like this at the top of each of your .htaccess files:

*

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^[\s/]*$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```