# FallbackResource + https redirect + Hide PHP extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

At the risk of this being a possible duplicate, I will ask anyway.  I've tried every answer for every similar question I could find.

I have apache set up with a FallbackResource set to /index.php and an https redirect.  My .htaccess looks like this:

```
FallbackResource /index.php

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So far so good.  My objective is the following:
For purely esthetic reasons, I would like to hide the php extension at the end of my urls.  All my links point to php files.  Is that possible?

So if someone types example.com/page_requested.php in the browser, I would like them to be directed to example.com/page_requested.php but that the person see example.com/page_requested

Possible?

Thanks a million.

Your going to save my brain from going into nuclear fusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect loop with simple htaccess rule](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18972017/342740)

Comment: Wasn't able to apply that answer...

Comment: `Wasn't able to apply` sorry but my crystal ball is not working could provide more information?

Comment: I think that because I have FallbackResource and want to hide the extension, the solution you are referring to is not working. And it doesn't apply really directly to what I am trying to do.

Comment: You don't need the fallback with that rule and you could simple define a default 404 to a main php which would produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A rule like this would drop the .php if it were present:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(\.php)?$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help covener.  It appears that the .php extension still persists with this rewrite rule...