# How can I simplify this Apache rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

In ~/public_html/foo I have an .htaccess file which appends a .php extension to non-existing files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~august/foo
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

Ideally, I would like to make this .htaccess file independent of where the project folder foo is stored. Is there a way to rewrite(!) the rules to eliminate /~august/foo?

Comment: That's my bad misread, you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971996/redirect-loop-with-simple-htaccess-rule it will basically find the path based on the root and url.

Comment: @Prix I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Check your rewrite_log to see what it is doing so you know weather or not its giving the right or wrong folder so you know what to change it, that was an example and of course it needs to be changed to adapt to your case.

Comment: @Prix I cannot see why the rewrite doesn't work without the rewrite base; if I remove it and access the existing file bar.php I get a 404 page saying `The requested URL /home/august/public_html/foo/bar.php was not found on this server.` All I want to do is append a string to the URL and I'm surprised that it is this difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a rewrite condition which "extracts" the /~username/projectdir part of the request URI (or an empty string if not present) and prepend it in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/~[^/]*/[^/]*/)?
RewriteRule (.+?)/*$ %0$1.php
```